# sinatra CORS request not working

Tags: javascript, sinatra

It seems setting headers in sinatra is not working or I'm doing something wrong. I want to be able to send a request via CORS.

I have setup sinatra via rack using pow on macosx. My sinatra app is quite basic. I know I need to setup more security for the CORS. But first I need to get it working.

Extra info it's a simple contactform:

**contact.rb**

```
require "rubygems"
require "sinatra/base"
require 'pony'
require 'yaml'
require 'json'

class Contact < Sinatra::Base

  before do
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST"
    p response.headers.inspect
  end



  # Load the configuration file for the mailserver settings
  conf = YAML.load_file('configuration.yml')

  post '/contact/' do
    content_type :json

    p params.inspect

    if params[:email].empty?
      response[:status] = "error"
      response[:message] = "No email"
      response.to_json
    elsif params[:mailbody].empty?
      response[:status] = "error"
      response[:message] = "No message?"
      response.to_json
    elsif 

        Pony.mail(
          :to => params[:email] + "<" + params[:email] + ">",
          :from => 'me@gmail.com',
          :subject => params[:email] + " has contacted you",
          :body => params[:mailbody],
          :via => :smtp,
          :via_options => { 
            :address              => conf['smtp'], 
            :port                 => conf['port'], 
            :user_name            => conf ['user_name'],
            :password             => conf ['password'],
            :enable_starttls_auto => true, 
            :authentication       => :plain
          })
        response[:status] = "success"
        response[:message] = "Email sent. We will contact you as soon as possible"

        p.response.inspect

        response.to_json

      end

  end
end
```

**javascript on the client side**

```
// Contact form submission
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#contactForm').submit(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://cooldevops_contact.dev/contact/",
            data: $("#contactForm").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",

            success: function(msg) {
                $("#formResponse").removeClass('error');
                $("#formResponse").removeClass('success');
                $("#formResponse").addClass(msg.status);
                $("#formResponse").html(msg.message);

            },
            error: function() {
                $("#formResponse").removeClass('success');
                $("#formResponse").addClass('error');
                $("#formResponse").html("There was an error submitting the form. Please try again.");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Request header**

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 19
X-Cascade: pass
Date: Sun, 13 Jul 2014 08:24:54 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

it worked when everything was working via localhost. I used the sinatra CORS gem. This is the simples solution I thought should work. But it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was not with CORS or sinatra. The jquery was not working correctly and closed the connections before sinatra could return something.

Reworked the jquery code and now it works.